# Php - allow spaces in rewriteRule

Tags: php, url, seo, url-rewriting, rule

i have this current url rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

Now i need to add, that every space is replaced with a "-", but how can i add this to my rewrite? is this possible doing it this way?

Comment: Yo mean replace space in rewrite rule? with mod_rewrite, you cannot do a substitution. you should do it in the php code.

Answer (score 0):

You can accept spaces in your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([(a-zA-Z0-9_-]|\s)+)$ index.php?id=$1
```

Then in *index.php* you would have to replace the spaces with underscores:

```
preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', $id);
```